# How to make a full width Grid Item using MaterialUI in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can I make the size of a grid item take up the whole width? I can't find it in the material ui documentation.

[image: Please click this link to see image]

```
<Grid container>
   <Grid item md={12} lg={12} spacing={0}>
      <Header/>
   </Grid>
   <Grid item md={12} lg={12}>
      <Footer styles={styles.Paper}/>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The Grid that contains the Footer here is not taking up the full width, see the picture above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]You can use spacing property with Grid container

```
<Grid container spacing={40}>
    <Grid item xs={12} style={{paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0}}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks For the answer man But it didnt worked for me it still has a little space on both side any other ideas?

Comment: You have to remove the padding from Left and Right